# Ansible FAILED: python mysqldb module is required

Tags: debian, python, mysql, ansible

Please tell me how to install the module mysql_db in debian 9. I am writing a playbook in ansible. It was necessary to create a database and user. The documentation ansible says that the mysql_db module is used for this. Below on the same page there is information

> The Python package may be installed with apt-get install python-pymysql

**I install according to the instructions from the off site Ansible.**

```
xxxx@instance-3:/etc/ansible$ sudo apt-get install python-pymysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  python-pymysql-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pymysql
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 61.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 318 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 python-pymysql all 0.7.10-1 [61.4 kB]
Fetched 61.4 kB in 0s (987 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package python-pymysql.
(Reading database ... 55250 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-pymysql_0.7.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pymysql (0.7.10-1) ...
Setting up python-pymysql (0.7.10-1) ...
```

**Next I try to start the playbook.**

```
xxxx@instance-3:/etc/ansible$ ansible-playbook db.yml

PLAY [create data base] ********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [xx.xx.xx.xxx]

TASK [db] **********************************************************************
fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "the python mysqldb module is required"}
 [WARNING]: Could not create retry file '/etc/ansible/db.retry'.         [Errno 13] Permission denied:
u'/etc/ansible/db.retry'


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
xx.xx.xx.xxx               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**My playbook for ansible**

```
---
- name: create data base
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: db
    mysql_db:
     name: bobdata
     state: present

  - name: user
    mysql_user:
     name: wpuser
     password: 123456
     priv: '*.*:ALL'
     state: present
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Install python mysqldb module in the remote host.

**Details**

> FAILED! => { ... "msg": "the python mysqldb module is required" ...

Quoting from [Requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_db_module.html#requirements)

> The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.

- MySQLdb (Python 2.x)
- PyMySQL (Python 2.7 and Python 3.X), or
- mysql (command line binary)
- mysqldump (command line binary)

---

"`The host that executes this module`" is the **remote host**.

For example in FreeBSD (as a remote host)

```
$ pkg info | grep -i MySQLdb
py27-MySQLdb-1.2.5_1           Access a MySQL database through Python
```

FWIW, there is an open issue [The MySQL-python module is required #906](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container/issues/906) with Debian.